# Разбор файла *.ITK c с помощью python определенной структуры

Tags: python, файлы, struct

Файл не является изображением, представляет собой некий файл данных, каким образом можно расковырять данный файл и расопознать данные. Структура идет сначало время, затем, данные канала 1, канал2, канал3, по записываемым каналам.
Как то можно вымести структуру методом print? C python впервые, подскажите кто чем?

c       |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|0A|0B|0C|0D|0E|0F|

c 0000: |YY|MM|DD|HH|NN|SS| mSS | SMPL   |CH| CAL |  |  |

c 0010: | STN |\0   | |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

c 0020: | Ch.1| Ch.2| Ch.3| Ch.1| Ch.2| Ch.3| Ch.1| Ch.2|

c 0030: | Ch.3| Ch.1| Ch.2| Ch.3| Ch.1| Ch.2| Ch.3| Ch.1|

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос то нужно просто открыть файл прочитать и вывести данные, то попробуйте это:

```
with open(‘Ваш файл’,’r’) as file:
    print(file)
```

Comment: Даже так не работает, выводит: runfile('C:/kiwi/vlf/zd1.py', wdir='C:/kiwi/vlf')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='VLF05_20191226000000_40k_03.ITK' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>  и все я так понимаю надо воспользоваться структурой (struct) прочитав его

Comment: @Kalashnikov а это что?

Comment: не понял вопроса?

Comment: @Kalashnikov у вас файл в каком расширении? Код который я написал только .txt читает.